# Help to identify topcase RS661-07951 (replacement)

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, hardware

please help to identify "RS661-07951". I have MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports) and now have this topcase.

My previous keyboard has broken (keyboard's key sticking), i found link https://support.apple.com/en-euro/keyboard-service-program-for-mac-notebooks and went to a service centre and so there installed replacement topcase - listed in the paperwork as "RS661-07951".

Now i'm trying to figure out if this topcase may have the same problems as original or this replacement keyboard with silicone spacers (the presses have become softer)??

Comment: What do you mean with "identify topcase R..."? If you already have it in front of you, what kind of identification do you need?

Comment: I’m trying to know is this top case the same or with fixed keyboard problems?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: All the replacements are still butterfly keys.  The permanent fix for the issue is for them to not be butterfly keys.

Comment: I heard about silicone membrane for keyboard replacement. But it doesn't seem to be, found this -> "This solution required a different fit so the 2016 and 2017 MacBook Pro's could not be retrofitted with this new butterfly keyboard with the silicone membrane sheet." Thanks anyway for the replies.

Comment: 2018 laptops get the 2018 version of the replacement, that has the silicone membrane, 2016-2017's do not.  Different topcases.